# Como organizar um JSON por data

Tags: javascript, json, classificação

Eu tenho este JSON e devo organizá-lo por `data`:

```
{
    "clients": [
        { "id": 1, "name": "Juca" },
        { "id": 2, "name": "Beto" }
    ],
    "purchase": [
        { "client_id": 1, "data": "11/04/2021", "total": 100.0 },
        { "client_id": 2, "data": "11/03/2021", "total": 83.71 },
        { "client_id": 2, "data": "08/02/2021", "total": 52.48 },
        { "client_id": 1, "data": "20/04/2021", "total": 399.99 }
    ]
}
```

No caso eu tenho um arquivo (main.js) que importa o objeto do arquivo .json e imprime para cada cliente seus dados, suas compras ordenadas por data e o total em compras.

Esta é a resposta esperada:

---

Cliente 1 - Juca

Compra em 11/04/2021 no total de R$ 100.00

Compra em 20/04/2021 no total de R$ 399.99

Total do cliente: R$ 499.99

Cliente 2 - Beto

Compra em 08/02/2021 no total de R$ 52.48

Compra em 11/03/2021 no total de R$ 83.71

Total do cliente: R$ 136.19

---

Eu já tentei usar `sort()` manipulação de string usando o `split('/')` mas nada me retorna a resposta esperada.

Obs.: a execução do código deve ser feita usando node --experimental-json-modeules main.js

Comment: Sua pergunta está um pouco ambígua, sugiro [edit] para colocar o resultado esperado. O formato do JSON deve permanecer o mesmo, apenas ordenando o `purchase` por `client_id` e posteriormente `data`?

Comment: Concordo com o @RafaelTavares referente a isto. Respodi sua pergunta baseado no que consegui extrair (*talvez com uma solução onde podes tentar aplicar em seu projeto*)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

### Atualizado

Se for pra organizar por código do cliente e as datas em ordem crescente (as duas coisas), aí você pode usar um `.sort()` com um `return` dentro de um `if` comparando as datas caso o código do cliente seja igual nos dois argumentos da função do `.sort()`, ou então retornando o código do cliente na ordem menor para maior, conforme código abaixo:

```js
var data = {
    "clients": [
        { "id": 1, "name": "Juca" },
        { "id": 2, "name": "Beto" }
    ],
    "purchase": [
        { "client_id": 1, "data": "11/04/2021", "total": 100.0 },
        { "client_id": 2, "data": "11/03/1998", "total": 83.71 },
        { "client_id": 2, "data": "08/02/2021", "total": 52.48 },
        { "client_id": 1, "data": "20/04/2021", "total": 399.99 },
        { "client_id": 3, "data": "20/04/2021", "total": 1.99 },
        { "client_id": 4, "data": "20/04/2019", "total": 2.99 },
        { "client_id": 1, "data": "29/12/2021", "total": 4.99 },
        { "client_id": 2, "data": "01/01/1990", "total": 5.99 },
        { "client_id": 3, "data": "19/04/2021", "total": 7.99 },
        { "client_id": 4, "data": "21/01/1990", "total": 7.99 }
    ]
}

function dataFormat(d){
   
   var d_split = d.split("/");
   var dia = d_split[0];
   var mes = d_split[1]-1; // diminui por 1 porque os meses começam com 0
   var ano = d_split[2];

   return [dia,mes,ano];
}


data.purchase.sort(function(a,b){
   if(a.client_id == b.client_id){
      return new Date(dataFormat(a.data)[2], dataFormat(a.data)[1], dataFormat(a.data)[0]) - new Date(dataFormat(b.data)[2], dataFormat(b.data)[1], dataFormat(b.data)[0]);
   }
   return a.client_id - b.client_id;
});
 

console.log(data.purchase);
```

Observe que nas datas, no objeto `new Date()`, usei o padrão `ano, mês, dia` para comparar se uma data é menor (mais antiga) que a outra.

O resultado do código acima é:

```
0: {client_id: 1, data: "11/04/2021", total: 100}
1: {client_id: 1, data: "20/04/2021", total: 399.99}
2: {client_id: 1, data: "29/12/2021", total: 4.99}
3: {client_id: 2, data: "01/01/1990", total: 5.99}
4: {client_id: 2, data: "11/03/1998", total: 83.71}
5: {client_id: 2, data: "08/02/2021", total: 52.48}
6: {client_id: 3, data: "19/04/2021", total: 7.99}
7: {client_id: 3, data: "20/04/2021", total: 1.99}
8: {client_id: 4, data: "21/01/1990", total: 7.99}
9: {client_id: 4, data: "20/04/2019", total: 2.99}
```

Answer (score -3):

### Com base na sua pergunta encontrei a seguinte solução..

Em resumo, armazenei as datas em um novo `Array` e transformei-os para timestamp, em pesquisa, um instante único [de acordo com o blog do hkotsubo](https://hkotsubo.github.io/blog/2019-05-02/o-que-e-timestamp). Por ser um ponto específico na linha tempo, ou seja, sofre alterações crescentes de acordo com o passar do tempo, assim conseguimos tratar essas datas sem ter a necessidade de transformá-las em números, o que traria uma série de conflitos..

```js
// para fins de obter as datas, basta você percorrer todo o json e obter as respectivas datas conforme deseja..
var datasArr = ["11/04/2021", "11/03/2021", "08/02/2021", "20/04/2021"];

// transforma o datetime para timestamp
const timestamp = input => Math.floor(Date.parse(input) / 1000);

// mapeio todo o array contendo as datas e os formato em "yyyy mm dd"
datasArr = datasArr.map(data => {
   var [dia, mes, ano] = data.split("/").map(d => d.padStart(d.length, "0"));
   return timestamp(`${ano} ${mes} ${dia}`);
});

// imprime as datas formatadas para timestamp..
console.log(datasArr);
```

**Ótimo datas formatadas!** como mencionado na pergunta, utilizei a própria função [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) do [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) para ordenar esses valores do menor para o maior

```js
var datasArr = ["11/04/2021", "11/03/2021", "08/02/2021", "20/04/2021"];

const timestamp = input => Math.floor(Date.parse(input) / 1000);

datasArr = datasArr.map(data => {
   var [dia, mes, ano] = data.split("/").map(d => d.padStart(d.length, "0"));
   return timestamp(`${ano} ${mes} ${dia}`);
});

// aqui ele vai ordenar as datas no formato de timestamp, assim na hora de converter 
// as datas estarão ordenadas do menor para maior e no formato dd/mm/yyyy
datasArr = datasArr.sort((a, b) => {
   return a - b
});

var convertDatasArr = datasArr.map((timestamp) => {
   return new Date(timestamp * 1000).toLocaleDateString("pt-BR");
});

// imprime as datas no formato dd/mm/yyyy de forma ordenada
console.log(convertDatasArr);
```

---

<sup>**Obs.:** vale ressaltar que o código acima corresponde a *"como organizar as datas da mais antiga para a mais nova."* Portanto fico no aguardo do autor utilizar os critérios de [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para incluir mais detalhes na pergunta, para assim poder de fato saná-la por completo!</sup>

Comment: Transformar em número não é uma boa porque tem casos que pode ter zero à esquerda. Por exemplo, se tiver "08/12/2021" e "20/04/2021" (8 de dezembro e 20 de abril), ao transformar em números eles viram 8122021 e 20042021 (8 milhões e 20 milhões), e vai dizer que 20 de abril é maior (sendo que 8 de dezembro é maior). O ideal é transformar tudo em `Date` mesmo, e nem precisa criar funções para o maior e menor, basta usar `Math.max` e `Math.min`. E claro que ainda tem o trabalho de converter de volta ao formato original. Algo assim: https://ideone.com/lFMd3y

Comment: De qualquer forma, a pergunta ainda não está clara e não sei se isso responde de fato. Pelo que entendi, ele quer ordenar as datas segundo algum critério, e não pegar somente a maior e menor. Vamos aguardar pra ver se o autor esclarece melhor...

Comment: Ok, em seguida corrijo a resposta, fiquei meio com um pé atrás também, sei que ele não quis obter menor e maior valor, porém baseado na pergunta foi a solução que encontrei.. aguardo o esclarecimento do autor!

Comment: @hkotsubo problema solucionado! corrigi até o momento essa questão dos casos de ter *"zero à esquerda"*

Comment: Se vc já separou os valores do dia, mês e ano com `split`, podia usá-los diretamente, como eu fiz [aqui](https://ideone.com/lFMd3y). Transformá-los em outra string para passá-la para `Date.parse` é uma volta desnecessária. Sem contar que não é recomendado usar formatos não padronizados, porque não é garantido que funcione igual em todos os browsers (entenda melhor lendo [aqui](/a/408168/112052)). E também não entendi pra que dividir o timestamp por 1000 só pra depois multiplicar por 1000 (nesse caso não faz diferença, mas se tivesse o horário, o `floor` faria perder as frações de segundo)